# Is it possible to show a fixed view of a website in webView

Tags: android, eclipse, webview

I am planning to add a webView of my website with some tables and feeds on it.  Because I have been having such trouble parsing it I wondered is it possible load the part of the website with the table in a fixed view, disabling scroll and any options other than back to the list view.

Any idea's??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what u want dear i cant get u

Comment: u want to show web view in whole screen with perfect view and scroll